# How to eliminate the popup window in Google Maps new code?

Tags: google-maps, popup

How do I get an embedded Google Map not to show the pop-up window above the location marker on the map?

One used to change "iwloc=A" to "iwloc=near", but "iwloc does not appear in the code Google gave me.

Here is the code:

```
<iframe width="760" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?client=safari&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;q=1324+Portesuello+Ave,+Santa+Barbara,+CA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1324+Portesuello+Ave,+Santa+Barbara,+California+93105&amp;gl=us&amp;t=m&amp;ll=34.415053,-119.726944&amp;spn=0.033988,0.065145&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?client=safari&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;q=1324+Portesuello+Ave,+Santa+Barbara,+CA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1324+Portesuello+Ave,+Santa+Barbara,+California+93105&amp;gl=us&amp;t=m&amp;ll=34.415053,-119.726944&amp;spn=0.033988,0.065145&amp;z=14&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: then add it to the url

Comment: @Dr. Molle: Do you mean add "iwloc=near" to the src url? I tried that. The result is that the iframe then shows the google page one would see in a browser, not just the map.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/UTafv/

Comment: Yes! Thank you Dr.Molle. (The devil, or God, is in the details!)